# How do I load a BufferedImage as a resource and where do I place it?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

Consider the following class:

```
final public class ResourceLoader
{
    public BufferedImage bg;
    public BufferedImage tile;
    public ResourceLoader()
    {

    }
}
```

My goal is to be able to access the image files like this:

```
ResourceLoader res = new ResourceLoader();
// I can display res.bg and res.tile now.
```

What do I need to write inside the constructor and where do I need to put the images so that they'll work both during debugging and after they're packed in the .jar? I'm using Eclipse.

Also, is there a better way to do this? (I only need to load them once)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem really comes down to 'How to access resource on the run-time class-path of the application?'. So..

> How do I load a BufferedImage as a resource..

If you mean 'application resource' (I.E. supplied by you, with the application, as opposed to an image identified by the user).  Then the answer is typically:  from the class-path: E.G.

```
this.getResource("/path/to/the.jpg");
```

> .. and where do I place it?

At `/path/to` in a Jar on the run-time class-path.  Note that this will also work in development (with loose or 'unjarred' resources), so long as the class-path is correct.

Comment: Yes, I meant application resource, sorry. I ended up using `bg = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("resources/bg.png"));` and it seems to work, but Eclipse won't include the resources folder in the .jar even though I added it as a source folder (it works fine if I add it manually). How do I achieve that?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure.  I would tend to write an Ant script that does it all (eclipse runs Ant scripts), but that clashes with the usual 'IDE way'.

Comment: You're welcome. :)  Hope it all works out for you.  If not, it might pay to ask a more 'eclipse specific' question.

Answer (score -1):

You want to assign once i.e. load once then you can do the following class design

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

final public class ResourceLoader {
    private final BufferedImage bg;
    private final BufferedImage tile;

    public ResourceLoader(BufferedImage bg, BufferedImage tile) {
        this.bg = bg;
        this.tile = tile;
    }

    public ResourceLoader() {
        try {
            bg = ImageIO.read(new File("images/image1.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            tile = ImageIO.read(new File("images/image2.jpg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public BufferedImage getBg() {
        return bg;
    }

    public BufferedImage getTile() {
        return tile;
    }
}
```

**Here your points satisfies by the following ways**

- There is not any `public` `setter` method, so that you can not assign the filed outside the class
- The fields are `private` and `final` hence you can not modify them after wards.
- If you want to access that fields then you can use the `getter` methods of the fileds to get the field values.

Comment: That's a good design, but I was trying to actually load the files from within the constructor.

Comment: You can write the code of the file loading within the constructor, its too easy

Comment: Every method I've tried so far would either not work with the files in the .jar, look for the files god knows where, or not work at all. I'm sorry if this was a stupid question, but I just can't grasp this whole resource thing.

Comment: I fail to see how this addresses the actual question.  Care to explain it?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Here questioner has asked the way of initializing the values such that it can be reatdable once at the time of initialization.

Comment: The copy/pasted question is *"What do I need to write inside the constructor and where do I need to put the images so that they'll work both during debugging and after they're packed in the .jar?"*  How does that collection of words even approach the question?  -1